# Executing the page's JavaScript from Selenium WebDriver

Tags: java, javascript, gwt, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm writing an automatic test for a website, and I'm trying to run a function that exists in this site.
When I open the developer tools I can see the function I'm trying to run in the page's JavaScript, when I run `alert('hello world')` from my code I can see it in the test page.
my code is:

```
WebDriver driver = getDriver();
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
String retval = (String) js.executeScript("return theFunction()");
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: does it work without the return?

Comment: no, it says that the function is not defined.

Answer (score 0):

I was using GWT, and before you use the function you need to reveal the function as described in [this link](http://googlewebtoolkit.blogspot.co.il/2008/07/getting-to-really-know-gwt-part-1-jsni.html) under the Creating JavaScript libraries with GWT section

You'll basically need to "publish" the function as follows:
`$wnd.publishedFuncName = @pakage.class::realfuctionName(D);`
the D stands for double as an input parameter, a fuller list of how to refer to variables can be found [here](http://refcardz.dzone.com/refcardz/html/gwt-style-configuration-and/gwt-style-configuration-and-2)
After doing that you can run the function as if you run it from the console, no `window.fuction` needed.

And also, I had to change the type of `retval` to be Object, and then used the `toString` function.